# Making Whatsapp Web not needing QR-scanning how this work - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I put this code to active without QR code...but it doesnt function.
I open de whatsweb, scan the QR and closed all. After I active the code bellow but its doesnt work. Could anybody help me?

```
     options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() options.add_argument(r"D:/pythonProject/Aulas/scripts/Projetos/whatsautomatico/driver/data")
     driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:\pythonProject\Aulas\scripts\Projetos\whatsautomatico\driver\chromedriver',options=options)   
    
     driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com') 
     time.sleep(15)
```

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

its because the selenium opens a browser without any cookies from your previous browser. Think of it as a private window

Comment: tkx for the answer..could you help me to solve this?

I need open it after I closed the window in regular navigator not in a private